# Matching if a csv row follows a particular pattern using regex

Tags: java, regex, csv

I want to write a regex which will return true if the any column of csv files starting from 3rd column up to end is a non zero value
    so in case the row is like

```
//sample code for which regex needs to be used    
121,321,0,0,0,0,0,0  it should return false
121,321,1,0,0,0,0,0  it should return true
121,321,0,0,0,0,1,0  it should return true


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String text = "1234,1102,0,0,0,0";
            String regex = "";
            System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regex, text));

            }
```

I am new to regex can anyone help me with this

Comment: Have you tried any regexes?

Comment: No need a start that how can such type of cases be handled using rejex.

Comment: I don't think you understand how this site works.  We are a question-and-answer site, not a code-writing service.  You have to show us that you have made an effort before we will help you.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I have tried this String regex = "[[[0-9]*[[^0]]],]*"; but its returning true everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
regex="^[0-9]+,[0-9]+,(0,)*(0)*[1-9]+.*$";
```

Comment: Thanks a tonn :) it worked for me.I will do soem more tetsing around it

Comment: It is failing in this case   String text = "1234,11002,0,0,01,0";

Comment: This won't work for longer lines: `121,321,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0`. The question does not state whether the csv lines are always uniform.

Comment: @Pharaoh actually it does work for longer lines - and specifically for the example you have provided.  Before claiming  something - please test first - you can test it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: I have tested it now and it does exactly what I thought. But I have misinterpreted the question. I've read *"the last three columns"*, while it states *"starting with the third column"*. See my answer, which is obviously wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

If the only condition is that the last three columns are *not* all `0`, the following easier regex works, too:

```
.*(?<!,0,0,0)$
```

Edit: I misinterpreted the question. It's not *"the last three"*, but *"all columns, starting with the third"*.